# How to add unique identifier to each level of nested array with unknown values?

Tags: php

I have array that contains 4 levels of nesting:

```
$data =  [
    "" => [            
            'sub_level_1' => [                    
                    'sub_level_2' => [
                            'sub_level_3' => [
                                      0 => ""
                                      1 => "val"
                                 ]
                        ]
              ]
        ],
    "top_level_2" => [            
            'sub_level_1' => [                    
                    'sub_level_2' => [
                            'sub_level_3' => [
                                      0 => ""
                                      1 => "some_val"
                                      2 => "foo"
                                 ]
                        ]
              ]
        ] 
];
```

I want to add other unique identifier for each nested level, so I use a counter on each level:

```
$top_level_counter = 0;
$sub_level_1_counter = 0;
$sub_level_2_counter = 0;
$sub_level_3_counter = 0;

foreach ($data as &$top_level)
{
    $top_level['top_level_id'] = $top_level_counter++;

    foreach($top_level as &$sub_level_1)
    {
        $sub_level_1['sub_level_1_id'] = $sub_level_1_counter++;

            foreach($sub_level_1 as &$sub_level_2)
            {
                $sub_level_2['sub_level_2_id'] = $sub_level_2_counter++;
                // and continue with the last level..
            }
    }
}
```

But as the example above, the keys can be empty (`""`) or even `null` because that's data from the database.

I end up getting errors related to invalid values, but I can't find out which.

I did figure that as I go inside each level, I have to check for:

```
if (is_array($sub_level_<x>)
```

because on each level above I already store the unique id which is not an array. But still, even with that, I get invalid input for `foreach` for example.
But I can't find out what's causing that, though I suspect it might be because of a `null` or empty value

Is there a better way to do that?

The reason I want to do it is to have an easier to work with identifier for each element in the array because the actual data is strings in another language.

Expected result would be:

```
$data =  [
    "" => [ 
            'top_level_id' => 0,           
            'sub_level_1' => [ 
                    'sub_level_1_id' => 0,                      
                    'sub_level_2' => [
                            'sub_level_2_id' => 0,
                            'sub_level_3' => [
                                      0 => ""
                                      1 => "val"
                                 ]
                        ]
              ]
        ],
    "top_level_2" => [  
            'top_level_id' => 1,            
            'sub_level_1' => [      
                    'sub_level_1_id' => 1,              
                    'sub_level_2' => [
                            'sub_level_2_id' => 1,
                            'sub_level_3' => [
                                      0 => ""
                                      1 => "some_val"
                                      2 => "foo"
                                 ]
                        ]
              ]
        ] 
];
```

Comment: _"But as the example above, the keys can be empty ("") or even null because that's data from the database."_ - but you are not even _using_ those keys anywhere - so how is that actually relevant?

Comment: Your second innermost foreach are both the same, `foreach($top_level as &$sub_level_1)` - makes no sense, the second one of those should be something like `foreach($sub_level_1 as &$sub_level_2)`

Comment: @CBroe but still I get invalid arguments supplied for `foreach` so I'm not sure what's causing that. Also I updated the post, it was just a copy-paste mistake, in my code it's as you said

Comment: It's still missing the dollar sign before the variable names in several places. Please show _proper_ code.

Comment: @CBroe I added `if (is_array($nesting_level) || is_object($nesting_level))` before each `foreach` and now it seem to work.. do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because your inner loops go over these new `somthing_somthing_id` properties you just inserted on the upper level as well now, but those are integers and not arrays.

Comment: Yes, that's also what I mentioned in my post but for that I added `if (is_array($sub_level_<x>)`. This worked at the first level, though at the 2nd inner level it didn't work and I had to add another condition, why wasn't `if (is_array($sub_level_<x>)` alone enough as it did in the first level? (It fixed the invalid error for the top level)

Comment: Can't tell you that, without seeing your exact code; can only guess that you perhaps made a mistake with the correct `x` to use in `$sub_level_<x>` somewhere again.

Comment: Why is `sub_level_3_id` missing in your expected output?

Comment: @nice_dev I just thought it would be too long there so I wrote the comment `// and continue with the last level.`, I can add it though 

Comment: @Stackerito Fair enough. Looking at your attempt, it won't be dynamic with respect to the no. of nested levels possible, let alone fixing the issues in it.

Comment: @Stackerito Can you test this once at your end? https://onecompiler.com/php/3yruw27w5

Comment: @nice_dev I tried on my data but it didn't work. Not only the numbering, but also the `id` naming is not as I expect. What I want is a general name for each level, not name that includes the data itself. So for example `top_level_id` for all the top level data, `nested_level_1_id` for all the first inner level and so on. Not `some_data_id`. (but also the numbering did not work as expected). What I need is that each level of nesting will have its own counter (so if top level has 20 items, it would be from 0-19, then if inner level has total of 50 items, the `id`s would be from 0-49 and so on)

Comment: @Stackerito Ok, but your expected output has `0` for all inner levels and `1` for the second subarray on all inner levels.